# Audit data changes with Debezium

Tags: hibernate-envers, debezium, audit-trail, audit-tables

I have a use case where I want to audit the DB table data changes into another table for compliance purposes. Primarily, any changes to the data like Inserts/Updates/Deletes should be audited. I found different options like **JaVers**, **Hibernate Envers**, **Database triggers**, and **Debezium**.

I am avoiding using JaVers, and Hibernate Envers as this will not capture any data change that happens through direct SQL queries and any data change that happens through other applications. The other issue I see is we need to add the audit-related code to the main application code in the same transaction boundary.

I am also avoiding the usage of database triggers as we are not using triggers at all for any of the deployments.

Then I left with Debezium which is promising. But, the only concern that I have is that we need to use Kafka to leverage Debezium. **Is Kafka's usage is necessary to use Debezium if both the primary table and the audit table sit in the same DB instance?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debezium is perfect for auditing, but given it is a source Connector, it represents just one part of the data pipeline in your use case. You will capture every table change event (c=create, r=read, u=update, d=delete), store it on a Kafka topic or local disk and then you need a Sink Connector (i.e. Camel Kafka SQL or JDBC, kafka-connect-jdbc) to insert into the target table.

For the same transaction boundary requirement you can use the [Outbox Pattern](https://debezium.io/blog/2019/02/19/reliable-microservices-data-exchange-with-the-outbox-pattern/) if the eventual consistency is fine. There is also an [Outbox Event Router SMT](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.4/configuration/outbox-event-router.html) component that is part of the project.

Note that Debezium can also run [embedded in a standalone Java application](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.4/development/engine.html), storing the offset on local disk, but you lose the HA capability given by KafkaConnect running in distributed mode. With the embedded mode, you are also swtiching from a configuration-driven approach to a code-driven one.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I have follow-up questions. 1. Can we configure Debezium to capture only specific tables instead of all tables in the schema? 2. Is there any reference to the clients who are using Debezium in their production?

Comment: 1. Debezium is configurable. You can set which table to "replicate" and also what events (crate/read/update/delete). 2. Debezium is production ready. What should you look at is Kafka installation and set-up (if you have no prior experience). It is not hammer for all problems.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) to be a very comprehensive solution, and it is open source backed by Redhat. That gives it not only the credibility, but the security that it is going to be supported.

It provides a rich configuration to whitelist, blacklist databases/tables/columns (with wild card patterns), along with controls to limit data in really large columns.

Since it is driven from BinLogs, you not only get the current state, you also get the previous state. This is ideal for audit trails, and you can customize building a proper Sync to elastic topics (one for table).

Use of Kafka is necessary to account for HA and latency when bulk updates are made on DB, even though Primary and Audit tables are in same DB.